# Join two tables without extra rowes

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I tried a lot allready, but im not getting the result that i want.

Lets say i got the following data in the first table:

```
ColA  ColB   ColC  ColD
AA     11     1    50€
AA     11     1    60€
AA     11     1    10€
BB     22     1    15#
```

And in Table B I have this:

```
ColA  ColB   ColC   ColD
AA     11     1      Delta
AA     11     1      Delta
AA     11     1      Delta
BB     22     1      Gamma
BB     22     1      Gamma
```

I need to create a table that looks like this - note only the  4 rows, not the 11 that the inner join I was using produces.

```
ColA  ColB   ColC  ColD     ColE
AA     11     1    50€      Delta
AA     11     1    60€      Delta
AA     11     1    10€      Delta
BB     22     1    15€      Gamma
```

If anyone has an idea on how to make this work that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are there 5 rows in Table B? Is it not enough to have only two rows in there given the data you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ColA,
   A.ColB,
   A.ColC,
   A.ColD,
   B.Cold AS ColE
FROM Table_A AS A
JOIN Table_B AS B
  ON B.ColA = A.ColA
 AND B.ColB = A.ColB
GROUP BY A.ColA,
   A.ColB,
   A.ColC,
   A.ColD,
   B.Cold
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
SELECT A.ColA,A.ColB,A.ColC,A.ColD,B.ColD as BCol
FROM TableA A JOIN
     TableB B ON A.ColA=B.ColA AND A.ColB=B.ColB AND A.ColC=B.ColC
GROUP BY A.ColA,A.ColB,A.ColC,A.ColD,B.ColD
```

Result:

```
COLA    COLB    COLC    COLD    BCOL
AA      11      1       10€     Delta
AA      11      1       50€     Delta
AA      11      1       60€     Delta
BB      22      1       15#     Gamma
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07d4d/7).

Answer (score -1):

Can you use this:

```
select a.ColA,a.ColB,a.ColC,a.ColD,b.ColD
from table_a a inner join table_b b
on a.ColA = b.ColA
group by a.ColA,a.ColB,a.ColC,a.ColD,b.ColD
```

Comment: your GROUP BY makes the result look ok but the JOIN is not correct, you should join on COLA and COLB